# Why scanf can't parse the input separate by / mark?

Tags: c, scanf

This is my program when I learn scanf function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int day, year;
    char monthName[20];

    printf("separate day by /\n");
    scanf("%d/%s/%d", &day, monthName, &year);
    printf("%d %s %d\n", day, monthName, year);

    printf("separate day by blank\n");
    scanf("%d%s%d", &day, monthName, &year);
    printf("%d %s %d\n", day, monthName, year);
    return 0;
}
```

The input and output are below:

```
separate day by /
3/Dec/2016
3 Dec/2016 0
separate day by blank
3 Dec 2016
3 Dec 2016
```

Why does the second / mark appears and so does the zero char? Is there any  way or tools to analysis such problem?

Comment: The first step would be *checking the return value of `scanf`*. If it doesn't return 3 (in this case), it hasn't set all of your variables.

Comment: `%s/` --> `%19[^/]/`

Comment: ＠BLUEPIXY  I suppose that your idea is correct too,  which make the scanf  recgnise the / mark.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings.  Amongst other things the parameters to `main()` are not used, so the signature should be: `int main( void )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your `%s` is getting everything after the first `/` character. So when your `%d` starts to read, there is nothing left.

You can clearly understand that output by doing this:

```
printf("separate day by /\n");
scanf("%d/%s/%d", &day, monthName, &year);
printf("%d---%s---%d\n", day, monthName, year);
```

Which yields:

```
separate day by /
3/Dec/2016
3---Dec/2016---0
```

The reason `scanf` is not respecting the second `/` as you expected is because `%s` doesn't stop at the `/`, it stops only on whitespace characters. Check this from the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/):

> **Any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first
>   whitespace character found**. A terminating null character is
>   automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the format character to `%[...]` to specify what characters are accepted, instead of the default used by `%s`.

You also need to specify the buffer size to prevent buffer overflows.

Use:

```
"%d/%19[^/]/%d"
```

or just use `strptime`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Well, `scanf()` **can** handle input with fields separated with a slash ('/'). Just **not for strings** (which is unfortunate in your case).
2. What you see is because you use an invalid separator character (slash) for strings. `scanf()` only accepts whitespaces (spaces, tabs, newlines) as separators for strings. This is because a string can potentially contain many different characters (of course you may ask why a valid string shouldn't contain a whitespace in it... Well, the creators had to select **some** characters. Many beginning programmer stumble upon this when they fail to get a string with whitespaces with `scanf()`...)
3. For numeric types a broader range of separators is possible in `scanf()`. You can use as separators all characters which are illegal for representing a number (the exact set of valid characters differs for integer numbers and for real numbers).